# How to append dynamic html with dynamic data in angular1?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

Basically I want to achieve like this scenario:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLTcK.png

My research led me to $compile, $trustAsHtml,at last directive. 
In $compile and $trustAsHtml I can only append static template or only html but can't use dynamic things such ui-sref, ng-click etc. 
So, I tried to create directive it is not working and also I am unable to add multiple template on click.

controller :

```
app.controller('Ctrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope',function ($rootScope, $scope) 
{     
   $rootScope.enableDirective=false;         
   if(userHasOneApp){// checking some at least one app then only do action
   $rootScope.appicon="img_url"; // data which i am passing
   $rootScope.appname="App_name"; // data which i am passing
   $rootScope.enableDirective=true;
}
}]);
```

custom directive:

```
app.directive('headerTemplate', function () {
    return {               
      template:'<a ui-sref="/event" ng-click="editIt()">'
              +'<img src="{{appicon}}"></a>'
                +'<span>{{appname}}</span>',
        scope:{                                
           appname:'=',
           appicon:'='
        }             
      };
    });
```

Header view :

```
<div> class="headerdiv">
    <ul ng-if="enableDirective">
        <li header-template appicon="appicon">
         </li>                      
    </ul>
</div>
```

Main view :

```
<div> class="maindiv">
    <ui-view></ui-view> <!--basically I want to append template here -->
    <button>Add next template</button>
</div>
```

Where I am doing wrong ?

Comment: What do mean by *not working*? though `ui-sref` should be statename like `ui-sref="event"` and even if that fixed, you can't fire `ng-click` & `ui-sref` same time. Because once you navigate to other page via `href`, `click` event will not get fired

Comment: so what i understand is u want to add a directive dynamically to your already running angular app?

Comment: when I used $trustAsHtml, ui-sref should generate link but it is not generating link as ui-sref="event" should generate linke as href="/event" @PankajParkar

Comment: @AnkitRaonka yest I want to achieve this using directive because in the case of directive i am getting link but not append feature.

Comment: @user7390851 ur problem got solved?

Comment: @Ankit No, still I am looking for some help to do . My problem you can think  as it is similar to flowexpress.built.io .

Answer (score 0):

Well i was facing the same issue
Check out the following link
This will surely help you.

I have implemented this and it worked in my scenario where i wanted to serve a directive when required i.e Lazy Loading of directive

> https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/838402/Lazy-loading-directives-in-AngularJS-the-easy-way